# WSO2 IS: claim-config.xml - Is it read only once, or every time the server is started up?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

[The WSO2 IS documentation reads](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Adding+Claim+Mapping#AddingClaimMapping-Addexternalclaim):

"The claim dialects configured in /repository/conf/claim-config.xml file get applied only when you start the product for the first time, or for any newly created tenants. With the first startup, claim dialects and claims will be loaded from the file and persisted in the database. Any consecutive updates to the file will not be picked up and claim dialects and claims will be loaded from the database."

Does this mean claim-config.xml is a file to seed the database and is only run once?  If it is only for seeding the database, that means the only way to update claims after the very first start of the server is to edit the database directly or update claims via the console, correct?

I'm trying to figure out the best way to update my claims for service providers in WSO2 IS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that the claim-config.xml is only run once.  After the database is seeded, the file is not read anymore.  Subsequent changes to the claim configuration are written to the WSO2CARBON_DB file which is located at WSO2_INSTALL_LOCATION\repository\database

Answer (score 2):

When WSO2 IS starts in the first time, or when creating a new tenant It reads the `claim-config.xml` file and populates the claims into the database. Then you can manage the claims as below methods,

- From management console. Please refer the documentation [1] for more
  details.
- Using `ClaimMetadataManagementService`. Please refer the
  documentation [2] for more details.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Claims
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Managing+Claims+with+APIs